# Python iterate through a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I am new in Python and I was curious if I can do something like this:
Let's say that I have a list of tuples and one variable like this:

```
list = [(123,"a"),(125,"b")]
variable = (123,"c")
```

Is it possible to search for the first element of the variable in the list like this?

```
if variable[0] in list[0]:
```

Comment: Yes. But I do not know if it has the effect you want. Now you have bascially written `123 in (123,"a")` which is correct. But if this was the second tuple, it would fail.

Comment: What problem did you have when you tried this?

Comment: I've given you two duplicates that cover both use-cases; finding all matching tuples, and testing all or any of the elements match.

Comment: For your case, `any(item[0] == variable[0] for item in list)`.